# How to get data form json object in window phone 8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

My json looks like:

```
[
  {
     fid: "1",
     forum_name: "Latest Product News",
     imagepath: "http://sourcingmachine.co.uk/iphone_images/news_icons/product-news.png"
  },
  {
     fid: "19",
     forum_name: "Latest Supplier News",
     imagepath: "http://sourcingmachine.co.uk/iphone_images/news_icons/supplier-news.png"
  }
]
```

How do I get this data in listbox?

#### EDIT:

I've done this by now:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
    webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += webclient_DownloadStringCompleted;
    webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("MyURI"));
}

private void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
    {
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
        this.DataContext = rootObject;
    }
}
```

This is my RootObject class

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fid")]
    public string fid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "forum_name")]
    public string forum_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imagepath")]
    public string imagepath { get; set; }
}
```

How could I assign the result to my `ListBox.ItemSource`?

Comment: Use JSON.net for deserializing your json string to C# object

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
InitializeComponent();

WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += webclient_DownloadStringCompleted;
webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("Your URI"));

private void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    try
    { 
        string data = e.Result;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GetNews>>(data);
            lstNews.ItemsSource = rootObject;
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

GetNews

```
class GetNews
{
    public string fid { get; set; }
    public string forum_name { get; set; }
    public string imagepath { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class YourModelObject
{
    public int fid { get;set; }
    public string forum_name { get;set; }
    public string imagepath { get;set; }
}
```

When you call the conversion from the JSON string

```
string yourJSON = "what you posted above";
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(yourJSON);
//values is a List<RootObject> if it succeds
```

Comment: But my json is on web.

Comment: @user3514721 Follow this guide if you can http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/14/getting-started-with-web-requests-amp-json-in-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: If you need help in the steps just ask

Comment: public MainPage()
{ InitializeComponent();
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.DownloadStringCompleted+=webclient_DownloadStringComplete;
webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("MyURI"));}
void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(objectsender,DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
            {
                
                var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
                this.DataContext = rootObject;lstNews.ItemsSource = new List<RootObject{rootObject} ;}}}}

Comment: IT give error like An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code.

Comment: @user3514721 Post your RootObject please

Comment: public class RootObject
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fid")]
            public string fid { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty (PropertyName = "forum_name")]
            public string forum_name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imagepath")]
            public string imagepath { get; set; }
            
        }

Comment: replace `RootObject` with `List<RootObject>`

Comment: How to call another json item in list selectedchanged item.

Comment: help to slove this issue  verdesrobert. Above json item is my menu and i have to call another json item in listbox selectchenged event from fid of firstjson. (Submenu).

Comment: @Viral what do you mean by call another json item in list selectedchanged?

Comment: @ verdesrobert it meaans i have bind my data to listbox, when i select  one item of listbox , it open another list page dynamically.
eg:suppose i selected firstiem (fid: "1",) it wiil show data which fid = 1 to other page.

Comment: My json is look Like:SELECT id as topic_id, poster, subject FROM bb_topics WHERE forum_id=optionid ORDER BY posted DESC limit 0,20

Comment: in above json optionid == fid

Comment: You should edit the question adding the resources you are using/are trying to use and explain what you want to do on the question not in the comments